# multiple Html.ValidationSummary's in a single .Net MVC page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have multiple Html.ValidationSummary's in a single .Net MVC page?

I have a create user and a login form on the same page and would like to have to summaries

Answer (score 1):

You can, but they will both display the same ModelState validation errors, which may not be what you want. You may want to create special ViewData items to present the errors separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your two summaries and stuff them in your view model. Then create a partial view to display the summaries.